# int bitrate = mediaformat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE) is returning NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I am new to mediaCodec and using MediaFormat for extracting the video information.
I am using:

```
int width = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_WIDTH);
int height  = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_HEIGHT);
int bitrate = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE);
```

Height and Width are OK, I am getting correct height and width but the bitrate part is throwing an NullPointerException.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference

Comment: Fixed the issue using MediaMetadataRetriever class. MediaMetadataRetriever m = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        m.setDataSource(filepath);
        int bitrate  = Integer.valueOf(m.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_BITRATE));
Worked for me :)

Comment: if that solves your question - please write it as answer and mark it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this issue using

> MediaMetadataRetriever class.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever m = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
m.setDataSource(filepath);
int bitrate = Integer.valueOf(m.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_BITRATE));
```

This worked